# Don't know how to specify not equal condition

Tags: java, collections

I have an ArrayList of objects.

I want to implement the following line of code.

```
while((matchlist.get(index).getSignature()).equals(signature))
```

But I want to change the logic so that the while statement is conditional on not equals.  But cannot find a java collection not equals.

For example in pseudocode

```
while((matchlist.get(index).getSignature()).NOTequals(signature))
```

Comment: You mean `while (!matchlist.get(index).getSignature().equals(signature))`? The boolean NOT operator is `!`

Comment: thank you - silly mistake....looking too deeply into collections...